# Prometheus (via Docker) - Reverse proxy (via Apache) redirect issue

Tags: linux, apache, docker, reverse-proxy, prometheus

**Environment**
OS: Redhat 7
ReverseProxy: Apache (only)
Deployed via: Docker

========================================================================

**Issue:**
Is it possible to make the change in Apache reverse proxy so that I can access the prometheus console by
"http://myserverurl/prometheus" -> "http://myserverurl/prometheus/graph"

instead of currently failing with
"http://myserverurl/prometheus" -> "http://myserverurl/graph" (FAIL)

After the reverse proxy, URL get redirected and /promethus disappeared.

In Grafana setting I was able to add option like

(#docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=grafana -e "GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://0.0.0.0/grafana" grafana/grafana)

Which allows me to access Grafana console by
"http://myserverurl/grafana" -> "http://myserverurl/grafana/login" (SUCCESS)

========================================================================

**Docker status:**
docker run -d --name prometheus -p 9090:9090 prom/prometheus
[image: Prometheus docker status]

**Tested configuration for proxypass: (Did not work)**
ProxyPass /prometheus http://0.0.0.0:9090/prometheus
ProxyPassReverse /prometheus http://0.0.0.0:9090/prometheus

**Action:**
Tried to access the "http://myserverurl/prometheus"

**Result Failed:**
404 page not found

========================================================================

**But it is working if I change the configuration as below:**
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:9090/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:9090/

Access the url "http://myserverurl/" -> "http://myserverurl/graph"

**Result success:**
[image]
========================================================================
***Also tried following combination - Does not work:***
ProxyPass /promethus/ http://0.0.0.0:9090/
ProxyPassReverse /promethus/ http://0.0.0.0:9090/

Answer (score 2):

In order to have prometheus itself listen on /prometheus and not / you need to add a runtime parameters:

--web.**route-prefix="prometheus"**

--web.**external-url="http://myserverurl/prometheus"**

(at least in binary prometheus-2.7)

Prometheus invocation:

```
prometheus --web.listen-address="127.0.0.1:9090" --web.route-prefix="prometheus" --web.external-url="http://myserverurl/prometheus"
```

and also add symetric Apache rev-proxy:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass        /prometheus http://127.0.0.1:9090/prometheus
ProxyPassReverse /prometheus http://127.0.0.1:9090/prometheus
```